# How to give Eclipse RCP ContentOutlineView TreeViewer focus properly and respond to selection events

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, rcp

How do you give the part containing a ContentOutlineView focus correctly when clicking on the `TreeViewer`?

I am creating my own Outline like view and when clicking on the `TreeViewer` in a `ContentOutlinePage` when the (view)part is not in focus does not correctly fire selection events. I need to click on the tab to bring the part into focus before the `TreeViewer`'s selection events fire.

I have created my own `FooBarOutlineView` that extends `PageBookView`. I am creating pages only for `FooBarModelView` parts and instantiating either a `FooOutlinePage` or a `BarOutlinePage` that extends `ContentOutlinePage`

My `BarOutlinePage` overloads the createControl method to add a content provider to the `TreeViewer`:

```
public class BarOutlinePage extends ContentOutlinePage {

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        super.createControl(parent);
        getTreeViewer().setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider(new MyTreeModel()));
        getTreeViewer().setLabelProvider(new MyViewLabelProvider());
        getTreeViewer().setInput("root");
    }
}
```

My `FooBarOutlineView` (trimmed for brevity) looks like:

```
public class FooBarOutlineView extends PageBookView {

    @Override
    protected IPage createDefaultPage(PageBook book) {
        MessagePage defaultPage = new MessagePage();
        initPage(defaultPage);
        defaultPage.setMessage("An outline is not available. (default page)");
        defaultPage.createControl(book);
        return defaultPage;
    }

    @Override
    protected PageRec doCreatePage(IWorkbenchPart part) {
        IPageBookViewPage page = null;
        if (part instanceof FooModelView)
            page = new FooOutlinePage();
        else if (part instanceof BarModelView)
            page = new BarOutlinePage();
        initPage(page);
        page.createControl(getPageBook());
        return new PageRec(part, page);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isImportant(IWorkbenchPart part) {
        return (part instanceof FooBarModelView);
    }
}
```

Any insights warmly welcomed!

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the standard content outline view using the `ContentOutline` class?

Comment: My FooBarOutlineView is responding to View's, not editors. I would be quite happy to put my outline pages into the existing Outline, if you can explain how? (I see I may be able to override the isImportant method)

Comment: @greg-449 I switched my ``FooBarOutlineView`` to extend ``ContentOutline`` and implemented getAdapter in my Views. Much neater (thanks!) but same focus problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

The normal `ContentOutline` class has this method override which I think you need in your `FooBarOutlineView`:

```
public void partBroughtToTop(IWorkbenchPart part) {
     partActivated(part);
}
```

Comment: I've added this, but I still see the same behaviour. Selecting the TreeViewer when it is not in focus does not bring the tab into focus.

Comment: What platform is this? On my Mac selecting anything in a view gives it focus immediately.

Comment: Windows 64bit JVM. I'll try the same code on my Macbook soon.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on either Mac or Win, also see the same behavious in ContentOutline in general